# Body background image not respecting size of body

Tags: css

So I put a hard width on the body, I don't understand why the background image wouldn't respect that size.

Even when I put a overflow:hidden on the body, it wont cut it off.

This is part of a mobile site creator, so I wanted the dimensions of the body to be smaller to simulate a smaller screen.

I didnt want to go with an iframe.

Any ideas?

http://cl.ly/Q2uf

http://cl.ly/Q30Q

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a background image, it will respect the size of the div. Make sure it isn't being repeated background-repeat:no-repeat; . I'm still not sure what you are asking unless you want the background image to fit inside the smaller box in the middle of the page. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well the background is applied to the body tag. So if I set the body to 320px, does the browser treat background-image different when applied to the body?

Comment: Try it in Dev tools. If you put a bg image on the body, and set the body width to 300, it wont clip the background. It will always be relative to the browser top left;

Answer (score 0):

The background of `body` extends to the whole viewport if `html` has no background.

So set the background of `html` to white or whatever you want first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to set an exact width of body. Perhaps there are some browsers that will allow that, but not all.

Instead add a parent div right inside of body that you can define it's exact width. Then the background image will only

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {width:300px; background:url("") repeat;}
</style>

<body>
<div id="container">
     //blah blah
</div>
</body>
```